# Blazor: How do I set the background-image of a CSS class at runtime?

Tags: css, blazor

I know I can do this at design time:

```
.page-background-class {
background-image:url(../images/image-name.png)
```

}

But how can I set the background image at runtime? I want to show the image of a logged in user. I would like to use a URL, but could also do embedded.

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right lines.  Forget the Javascript, you're in Blazor.  I can't see where your using this image so I can't talk specifics, but you need to think component - what is my user display thing.  How do I make it a component - everything in the Blazor UI is a component!

To make this easier to demo, I'll set the background color rather than the image on a component.

Create a Razor component - `MyBackground.razor`

```html
<div style=" background-color:@this.Color" @attributes="Attributes">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter] public string Color { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    private IDictionary<string, object> Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            var attr = "style";
            if (this.AdditionalAttributes != null)
                if (this.AdditionalAttributes.ContainsKey(attr)) this.AdditionalAttributes.Remove(attr);
            return AdditionalAttributes;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use this - I've added it to `Index.razor` in the standard template

```html
@page "/"

@using TestBlazorServer.Components

<MyBackground Color="@this.color" class="p-5" style=" background-color:black">
    <h1 class="border-primary">Hello, world!</h1>

    Welcome to your new app.

    <SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

</MyBackground>

@code{

    private string color { get; set; } = "#bbf";
}
```

I've added some extra attributes so you can see how these are handled by the component.  `class` gets passed through, while `style` get removed - the background is blue not black with a nice wide padded margin.

The base code for your component would look something like:

```html
<div style="background-image:@this.ImageUrl" @attributes="Attributes">
    @ChildContent
// Or Html code to build out my UserDisplay Component
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter] public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    private IDictionary<string, object> Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            var attr = "style";
            if (this.AdditionalAttributes != null)
                if (this.AdditionalAttributes.ContainsKey(attr)) this.AdditionalAttributes.Remove(attr);
            return AdditionalAttributes;
        }
    }
}
```

Put any specific component CSS in a component CSS file.  [MS Docs on Component CSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

You need a line of Javascript code as below:

```js
// Replace `https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0ff/0011ff` with your image path.
document.querySelector('.page-background-class').style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0ff/0011ff")';
```

```css
.page-background-class {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-background-class"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I also found this works: 

 .e-avatar.image2 {
        background-image: url('@PictureURL');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: 35%;
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-size: 2.5em !important;
    }